# Display column headers of csv file in new lines

Tags: linux, bash, sed

I am trying to find a way to display output of headers in csv in new lines.

```
>head -n 1 sample.csv
col1,col2,col3
```

Expectation :-

```
col1
col2
col3
```

Comment: Please show the relevant code and state the exact problem or error. A description alone is not enough. Also see [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Have you considered using awk or sed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simplest I can do:

```
$ head -n 1 sample.csv | tr ',' '\n'
col1
col2
col3
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try as below

**Code:**

```
line=$(head -n 1 filename.csv) #get first line of a file
final=$(echo $line | sed 's/,/\\n/g') #replace "," with "\n"
echo -e $final #output with "\n" as new line
```

**Single line:**

```
echo -e $(head -n 1 col.csv | sed 's/,/\\n/g')
```

**Example:**

```
bash-3.2$ cat col.csv
Column1,Column2,Column3,Column4,Column5
abc,123,qwe,789,oiu
adasd,4356,asd,324,dsfs
asd,,,,bash-3.2$ 
bash-3.2$ 
bash-3.2$ line=$(head -n 1 col.csv)
bash-3.2$ 
bash-3.2$ final=$(echo $line | sed 's/,/\\n/g')
bash-3.2$ 
bash-3.2$ echo -e $final
Column1
Column2
Column3
Column4
Column5
bash-3.2$
```

Good Luck !!